# Neo4J JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document

Tags: java, exception, neo4j, rdf, wordnet

When trying to import wordnet 2.0 RDF into Neo4J through **neosemantics**  [neosemantics](https://github.com/jbarrasa/neosemantics) extension for import queries with more than 64,000 records to be imported JDK throws below exception and only about 50000 records are imported.

***JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK. [line 1, column 1]***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On looking I found that ***entityExpansionLimit*** parameter's value has to be changed.  The default value of entityExpansionLimit after JRE 1.7_45 is [64000](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html)

To set this in Neo4j do the following;

- Open **Projects**
- Click on **Manage** on your database
- Go **Settings** of the database add
  `dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0`
- Click on **Apply**
- The database will be restarted; if not Restart it by clicking on restart button.

------OR-------

- Open the **neo4j.conf** file from **C:\Users\PC_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-XXXX\installation-3.X.X\conf**
- Add `dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0` and save the file.
- Restart the database.

You can rerun your query.

Hope it helps and saves time for those who run into same error.